# How to flush the cache of the auto complete in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

**How to flush the cache of the autocomplete in jquery?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the following code to flush the cache of the autocomplete.**

```
$(.selector).flushCache();
```